# Colorbox close, reopen and keep events

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I have a small functionality, which opens in a colorbox. I'd like to be able to close the colorbox and reopen it. But opening the box again, the events do not work any more.

Minimal example:

```
(function() {
    var $content = jQuery('<button>Test</button>');
    $content.on('click', function(){jQuery.colorbox.close()});
    jQuery.colorbox({
        width: '90%',
        height: '90%',
        html: $content
    });
    var $reopen = jQuery('<button>Reopen</button>');
    jQuery(document.body).append($reopen);
    $reopen.on("click", function() {
        jQuery.colorbox({
            width: '90%',
            height: '90%',
            html: $content
        });
    });
})()
```

With the code above, I open a colorbox and I can use the `$content` button to close the box (or doing something else). If I close the box and Reopen it withe the `$reopen` button, the on-click-event on `$content` does not work any more.

Any idea how to solve the problem? To test the example code, you can use http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/ to have the required libs jquery and colorbox included.

Comment: In your code, the 'onclick' event of 'Test' is not triggered, I think.

Comment: @jolmos Yes, this is no code for unit testing or something like this. You have to click it. In fact, with the current code, three clicks are necessary to reproduce the behavior. I just wanted to keep the example as simple as possible.

Comment: I have created this jsbin, changing the colorbox with 'alerts' calls... what would be the problem here? http://jsbin.com/hasufezewe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @jolmos I tried to reproduce it with jsbin in an automatic way, but it did not work as intended. You can run and test the code above on this page for example: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/

Comment: Try replacing your event listeners using the following style `$( document ).on( 'click', '.my-element-class', function() { /* my code */ } );` so that it will always react to elements as they are dynamically populated on the page. Load those event scripts on your main page, and not within the lightbox.

Comment: Ok, now I got the point of the questions... This 'colorbox' seems to remove the node at closing. Then, when is reopen, a new node is created from the same jQuery object, but the click event was attached to the first DOM node that doesn't exist anymore. Take a look here: http://jsbin.com/royuxeruxu/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @LionelRitchietheManatee My application works with view-objects similar to backbone. Your approach would implement a global event handler and it would take a huge rewrite in my case (or is there a lib which automates this?). But for simple use cases like my example code, this would be good solution, imho.

Comment: @jolmos At first, it was my thought too. But it seems, colorbox removes events on closing.

Comment: It actually removes node(`<button>Test</button>`) and his associated event, on closing (you can check it in the console). So, to keep the click handler, either you make a global event handler based on class name (like @LionelRitchietheManatee suggest) or you can bind the 'test' click handler inside the reopen click handler.

Comment: @jolmos thanks for the help, with the clue to the `jQuery.remove()` function, I found a way around. I posted an answer by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the removing of the content, if colorbox is closed. A workaround is using the **inline** option to get the desired effect:

```
(function() {
    var $content = jQuery('<button>Test</button>');
    $content.on('click', function(){jQuery.colorbox.close()});
    jQuery.colorbox({
        width: '90%',
        height: '90%',
        inline: true,
        href: $content
    });
    $reopen = jQuery('<button>Reopen</button>');
    jQuery(document.body).append($reopen);
    $reopen.on("click", function() {
        jQuery.colorbox({
            width: '90%',
            height: '90%',
            inline: true,
            href: $content
        });
    });
})()
```

Using the **inline** option and moving the node from **html** to **href** saves your event handlers and allows you to reuse the node later. Colorbox replaces the `$content` with a dummy `<div>` and switches back on calling `close()`.